# RC522 Reads card but not tag

Tags: arduino, rfid

Dear Fellow Engineers,

I have just recieved two RC522 modules from eBay, both of them came with a card and a tag. Both of them read the cards just fine with miguelbalboa's library (https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid). But it does nothing when I am trying to use the tags. I have also tryied using the sainsmart library: cards ok, tags no joy.

What could possibly cause this issue?

I am working with an Arduino MEGA.

~Z

Comment: Same problem. The RC522 module I ordered from Aliexpress can read a card, but not a tag. Let me know if you found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

it happened to me recently. After a lot of searching and trial and errors, I found out that the frequency of the tags didn't match that of the reader. I am sure that the tags are not of matching frequency assuming they are OK, otherwise they might be faulty.
Only these two are possible answers.
Let me know what you find.
:)

Comment: Well they were shipped with the readers. So I assume they are on the same freq. Maybe faulty tags but I have got 2 from different sellers none of them work.

Comment: Ask the seller for a refund or replacement

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an old post now and I'm not sure whether you have figured out or not. But just to help others who might come here for the same reason.
I had the same problem and after long searching on google I figured out that run the RFID on 5v instead of 3.3v. I was a bit confused and afraid because the device itself says 3.3v for the power line, how come it would work good for 5volts?

Anyway, I wanted to give it a shot and believe me it really worked for me. And now I can use both my tags and cards without any issues.
Hope this helps people.

Comment: Well we are using cards now, they tend to break quite quickly so I have quite some work with them. I will give this a go! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I have three RFID-RC522 readers, two chain-tags and multiple cards. All card readers are supplied from 3.3V. One card reader was lent to me by a colleague (he bought it from ebay some time ago).

His card reader works with all tags and cards (including Opal cards, some debit and credit cards, etc). The other two readers I bought from ebay recently and they can only read the tags. His reader has 7 pins and no led and the chip is marked RC522 and the PCB is marked MF522-AN.

My 2 readers have 8 pins and a led and the chips are unmarked (there is only one dot on them, no text) and the PCB is marked RFID-RC522. So I think the solution to supply them from 5V is just a compromise, to compensate for something else (I don't know for what at the moment).